# How to Solve the Problem of Apache Not Starting

Tags: php

[image]

I want to open the server and set up the website, but Apache service is already available and still can't start.

I tried to enter `httpd.exe-t` and `httpd.exe-k` start in `cmd`, but neither could I.

win10
Listening port is `Listen 8080`

How can I open Apache in this way?

Doesn't it help to add pictures?
I didn't understand it at first.
Here are the error.log file

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwmyV.jpg)

Comment: What is the operation system?

Comment: @dılosürücü - The screen shot is from Windows + they are using `httpd.exe` so I think it's safe to assume it's Windows.

Comment: I cant showing your link of picture!